# Haskell: Monads and the (:) operator

Tags: haskell, monads

I have the following:

```
parseExtensions :: GHC.Int.Int64 -> Get [Word32]
parseExtensions size = do
    br <- bytesRead
    if (size - br > 20) 
        then do
            ext  <- parseExtension
            exts <- parseExtensions size
            return $ ext : exts
        else return []

parseExtension :: Get Word32
parseExtension = do
    name <- getWord32be
    size <- getWord32be
    info <- getBytes (fromIntegral size)
    return name
```

The idea is pretty simple. I'm using Data.Binary.Get to read data off a file. As long as I still have data available (size - br > 20), parse it and repeat.

Is there a simpler/shorter/better way to write the "then" in the parseExtensions function? Can't help but feel I can get some sort of tail recursion or something going.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shorter:

```
liftM2 (:) parseExtension (parseExtensions size)
```

Better, I'm not sure :-\

Comment: I'd say it is better, though I always liked Applicative / Monadic cons, i.e. `<:> :: Applicative f => f a -> f [a] -> f [a]` Unfortunately it isn't in the standard libraries, I first saw it in Clean's parser combinator library.

Comment: In straight-up applicative style, that's `(:) <$> parseExtension <*> parseExtensions size`